# How to pass dynamic arguments into Wordsmith chop parameters?

Tags: plugins, params

I have a use case where I need to set a `maxChars` variable to pass into the Wordsmith plugin’s `chop` parameters.

So I know I can do this (with the [Empty Coalesce plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/empty-coalesce)):

```
{% set maxChars = matrixBlock.maxChars ??? null %}
{% set intro    = entry.intro ??? null %}

{% if intro and maxChars %}
    {% set intro = intro|md|chop(limit= maxChars, unit='c', allowedTags='<p><em><strong><a>') %}
{% endif %}

…

<div class="whatever">
    {{ intro|raw }}
</div>
```

But `maxChars` might be `null` and I might want the `allowedTags` string to be a variable too, so it would be handy to be able to set the chop parameters as a hash and pass them in.

The following doesn’t seem to work, but is there something that does?

```
{# Default tags permitted #}
{% set chopArgs = { allowedTags: '<p>' } %}

{# Custom tag list #}
{% set tagList = matrixBlock.tagList ??? null %}

{% if maxChars %}
    {% set chopArgs = chopArgs|merge({ limit: maxChars, unit: 'c' }) %}
{% endif %}

{% if tagList %}
    {% set chopArgs = chopArgs|merge({ allowedTags: tagList }) %}
{% endif %}

…

{% if intro %}
    {% set intro = intro|md|chop(chopArgs) %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your only problem here is `limit` but would something like this work for you?

```
{# Default tags permitted #}
{% set defaultTags = "<p>" %}

{# Concatenate default + custom tags #}
{% set allowedTags = defaultTags ~ matrixBlock.tagList ?? null %}

{# Limit - use if provided or set to unlimited using a huge number #}
{% set limit = matrixBlock.maxChars ?? 1000000000000000 %}

{% if intro %}
    {% set intro = intro|md|chop(limit= limit, unit='c', allowedTags=allowedTags) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You’re right. Thanks Oli